# Retrieving image file from relative folder using readfile() or file_get_contents() not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents, readfile, file-exists, public-html

My root folder is `public_html`. Outside of `public_html` I have a folder called `images`.
In order for me to retrieve images from this folder I query the database for correct image name & extension in a file that is stored inside `public_html` folder -> `forms` folder -> `check_images.php`

My database output is:

```
$output['filetype'] -> jpg
$output['name'] -> 1
```

The variable `$file` is the relative path + the filename + filetype, which makes `'../../images/1.jpg'`.

Now for some reason fetching the image doesn't work, however `file_exists()` is working fine.

The header is:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

What am I doing wrong? and why isn't `readfile()` or `file_get_contents()` working as it should when they are exactly the same folder as `file_exists()`

Entire code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/MhkAfY4s

What is currently being displayed is an empty image / or a broken image when being linked to.

**UPDATE**

1. First I check the URL: http://pastebin.com/Fz36GmVD
2. Then I run the image code: http://pastebin.com/fZSRuJ4r

Comment: Can you show more of the code you're trying to work with?

Comment: @Aborted Posted :) Ignore the `'` error in there. Its not there in the real application

Comment: `header('Content-type: image/jpeg);` ... it's missing the closing single quote. Maybe you're getting an error?

Comment: @Aborted See comment above

Comment: If you `echo` out the file contents, without the JPEG header, does it show anything?

Comment: @Aborted It's not returning anything.

Comment: @Aborted, I tried using absolute path and I got the image in return as text. However, when I change the header to image, just a empty image is returned.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077180/retrieving-image-file-from-relative-folder-using-readfile-or-file-get-contents/38199574#answer-38199574

Comment: @Семенихин-Максим I have... It's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is most likely that there is other output than the image, thus messing up the image binary data. Have a look at the source of the page, beware of any spaces before your `<?php` as well as any after the ending `?>`one (which you should omit, as it is not needed)

To further help with large file downloads I suggest you use XSendFile to handle the heavy lifting for you.

- For Apache: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/
- For NGINX: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/

**Update:**

To sum it up, the most likely reason to why it didnt work is the ob_start with gzhandler, simply removing it did not do anything, that probably because of the E-Tag and browser still showed cached content.

Comment: I have already checked the empty spaces. Nothing there. Whenever I remove the `image header` I get a bunch of random letters output on the page... and with `image header` I get nothing.

Comment: Can you pastebin the complete code, including the php-tags and also pastebin the full output, including headers.

Comment: I added the pastebin, see update. Its the full code. The output is simply just the standard broken image from the browser. No code being displayed.

Comment: View source and pastebin it still -- In one of the files you just added to the pastebin you use ob_start() and also with a gz_handler, did you just for testing try to remove those?

Comment: I tried removing both, now I just get a bunch of letter output, looks like the image binary.

Comment: right, so we are getting somewhere, now pastebin that and the headers (as shown in the developer tools)

Comment: This is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/BbAk0AKY and the header is: http://pastebin.com/PbzSX6Ce

Comment: I have no idea what I just did, however the problem solved itself... I removed the gz_handler completely from the code (commenting it out didnt seem to work) and then it all worked..

Comment: My guess is that the E-Tag and/or cache policy forced your browser to show old content. The ob_start with gzhandler was probably the reason.

Answer (score 0):

- You have done some small errors
- header('Content-type: image/jpeg') should go  before image content
- check you folder setting shout it be `../` or `../../`

So your is **php code:**

```
$file_name = (int)$routes[2];
$file = '../images/'.$file_name;

$sql = "SELECT i.image_filetype as filetype, i.image_type as type, i.image_key "
        . "FROM images i "
        . "WHERE i.image_deleted IS NULL "
        . "AND i.image_id = :filename LIMIT 1";

$results = $db_connect->prepare($sql);
$results->bindParam(':filename', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results->execute();
$db_image = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($db_image as $output){
    // PROFILE PICTURE
    if($output['type'] === '1'){
        $path = $file.'.'.$output['filetype'];
        if(file_exists($path)){
            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            echo file_get_contents($path);
            exit;
        }else{$error_code = 4;}
    }
}
die('1');
```

**updated code**:

not sure what you are doing wrong but below code works for me. So pls provide result details.
My image file id  `godaddy2.jpg` in parent `images` folder.

```
<?php
// ROUTES[2] IS = IMAGE_ID + UNIQID
// EXAMPLE: 23
//$file_name = (int)$routes[2];

$file_name = 'godaddy2';

//$file = '/home/husliste/images/'.$file_name;

$file = '../images/'.$file_name;
//
//$sql = "SELECT i.image_filetype as filetype, i.image_type as type, i.image_key "
//        . "FROM images i "
//        . "WHERE i.image_deleted IS NULL "
//        . "AND i.image_id = :filename LIMIT 1";
//$results = $db_connect->prepare($sql);
//$results->bindParam(':filename', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//$results->execute();
//$db_image = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$db_image[] = [
    'filetype' =>'jpg',
    'type' =>'1',
];

function checkPlanAccess($a){
    return true;
}
foreach($db_image as $output){
    if($output['type']){
        // CREATE HEADER
        switch($output['filetype']){
            case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
            case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg";break;
            default:
        }
        header('Content-type: '.$ctype);
        // CREATE FILE PATH
        $file_path = $file.'.'.$output['filetype'];
        // =========================================== //
        // PLAN
        if($output['type'] === '1'){
            if(checkPlanAccess($output['image_key'])){
                if(file_exists($file_path)){
                    echo file_get_contents($file_path);
                }else{$error_code = 4;}
            }else{$error_code = 4;}
        }
        // PROFILE PICTURE
        elseif($output['type'] === '2' && $check_session){
            if(file_exists($file_path)){
                $image = file_get_contents($file_path);
                echo $image;
            }else{$error_code = 4;}
        }
        // COMPANY LOGO
        elseif($output['type'] === '3' && $check_session){
            if(file_exists($file_path)){
                echo file_get_contents($file_path);
            }else{$error_code = 4;}
        }
        // CUSTOMER LOGO
        elseif($output['type'] === '4'){
            if(checkCustomerAccess($output['image_key'])){
                if(file_exists($file_path)){
                    echo file_get_contents($file_path);
                }else{$error_code = 4;}
            }else{$error_code = 4;}
        }
        // CUSTOMER PROJECT IMAGES
        elseif($output['type'] === '5'){
            if(checkCustomerProjectAccess($output['image_key'])){
                if(file_exists($file_path)){
                    echo file_get_contents($file_path);
                }else{$error_code = 4;}
            }else{$error_code = 4;}
        }
        // SUPPLIER LOGO
        elseif($output['type'] === '6'){
            if(checkSupplierAccess($output['image_key'])){
                if(file_exists($file_path)){
                    echo file_get_contents($file_path);
                }else{$error_code = 4;}
            }else{$error_code = 4;}
        }else{
            $error_code = 4;
        }
    }else{
        $error_code = 4;
    }
}
die('1');
?>
```

Comment: I have tested both of these, and there is still the same output. See updated code for latest test. However, when I add the wrong file path I get the output  `1`